# Ways to improve UI design?

Tags: android, user-interface

Hey, I spent A LOT of time learning about Android coding and I finally almost finished the code part of the project. The only thing that is holding me back from publishing my app is the bad user interface..
I have basic knowledge in Photoshop, and I tried to make good looking buttons and improve the UI of the app though I cant get a good interface.. I dont want to publish my app with the basic black background and gray buttons!
I dont want anything super fancy, I want a calm and simple design.
Can anyone suggest ways to make a simple UI for a simple app?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html), you may read [this](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/) but the design depends on your application... Search on google for more android UI samples